# Grub Rescue Deleted Linux Partition alongside Windows 7 not detected

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but I cant get it to work.

I use a PC with Windows 7 pro sp1 and Ubuntu 16.04 partitioned. A while ago my graphic drivers for Ubuntu broke and I wasnt able to fix it (Amd radeon hd). Later I deleted my Ubuntu and unfortunately grub (the whole partitions). I got the "Grub rescue message. No such partition." Couldnt start windows anymore..
I made a bootable USB with Windows 7 and tried to repair my Windows, but when I came to "Repair your computer", there was no C: drive with windows located. I continued with the Command prompt, but I couldnt list it with DISKPART. I startet windows repair and after restart I got following: atombios_crtc_mode_fixup radeon error unable to allocate a ppll

Then I gave up and made a USB stick with Ubuntu 16.04 (newest) and installed Ubuntu. Now I get to the Grub bootloader, but it wont recognize Windows 7. When I boot into Ubuntu, my Monitor turns off after a short duration. I can work with a Terminal with alt+ctrl+shift+f2. I tried to reinstall my graphicdrivers, but ended up with problems when reconfiguring the xserver-xorg.
I appreciate any help. Really need to save my windows

Comment: if you are removing ubuntu, you don't need to "repair windows" per se. what is needed is the windows bootloader to be installed in the MBR.  running the windows boot repair should fix it.

Comment: I already tried that, but didnt work. I got a Error message: atombios_crtc_mode_fixup radeon error unable to allocate a ppll.

Comment: Please don't bury important information in the comments. Important information needs to be edited into your Question. Comments are intended to help you improve your Question, not to start a dialogue.

Comment: Hello? I need help.. still

Answer (score 0):

I am finding that the best thing to do, is make a 5GB boot sector using a boot-usb. Then Install Windows, leaving alone that sector at the front of your disk.
Finally, install Linux using "Something Else" and make sure that the 5GB /boot partition is flagged correctly, default would be grub-boot.

As to your graphics problems, look for "oibaf"